# Searching for an object deep in nested arrays by id with the return of the entire tree with this object

Tags: javascript

There is an object with a multidimensional nested structure, and it is necessary to return the entire branch with this object at the end of the function, if it is a child, then return the entire path to it by object, if it is both a parent and a child, return the entire branch completely, including child elements

```
const data = {
  "id": 85,
  "title": "Objects",
  "address": "i=85",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "85/0:Simulation",
      "title": "Simulation",
      "parent": "Objects",
      "address": "ns=3;s=85/0:Simulation",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1001,
          "title": "Constant",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1001"
        },
        {
          "id": 1002,
          "title": "Counter",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1002"
        },
        {
          "id": 1003,
          "title": "Random",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1003"
        },
        {
          "id": 1004,
          "title": "Sawtooth",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1004"
        },
        {
          "id": 1005,
          "title": "Sinusoid",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1005"
        },
        {
          "id": 1006,
          "title": "Square",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1006"
        },
        {
          "id": 1007,
          "title": "Triangle",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1007"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

for example, if you need to find an element with id = 1006, it will output

```
{
  "id": 85,
  "title": "Objects",
  "address": "i=85",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "85/0:Simulation",
      "title": "Simulation",
      "parent": "Objects",
      "address": "ns=3;s=85/0:Simulation",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1006,
          "title": "Square",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1006"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

if you need to find an element with id = 85/0:Simulation, it will output the entire object

when using the recursive approach, it returns only the object that contains this value

```
const input = [{
  "id": 85,
  "title": "Objects",
  "address": "i=85",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "85/0:Simulation",
      "title": "Simulation",
      "parent": "Objects",
      "address": "ns=3;s=85/0:Simulation",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1001,
          "title": "Constant",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1001"
        },
        {
          "id": 1002,
          "title": "Counter",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1002"
        },
        {
          "id": 1003,
          "title": "Random",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1003"
        },
        {
          "id": 1004,
          "title": "Sawtooth",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1004"
        },
        {
          "id": 1005,
          "title": "Sinusoid",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1005"
        },
        {
          "id": 1006,
          "title": "Square",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1006"
        },
        {
          "id": 1007,
          "title": "Triangle",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1007"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

console.log(findNestedObj(input, 'id', 1006));

function findNestedObj(entireObj, keyToFind, valToFind) {
  let foundObj;
  JSON.stringify(entireObj, (_, nestedValue) => {
    if (nestedValue && nestedValue[keyToFind] === valToFind) {
      foundObj = nestedValue;
    }
    return nestedValue;
  });
  return foundObj;
};
```

at the output, I only get an object with this key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution that should solve your problem. I was having trouble printing the final structure so I added a recursive print function to show which elements are still present in the final structure.

Note that this assumes every ID in the entire list is unique, as if there are duplicates this will always return the first one found.

```js
const data = {
  "id": 85,
  "title": "Objects",
  "address": "i=85",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "85/0:Simulation",
      "title": "Simulation",
      "parent": "Objects",
      "address": "ns=3;s=85/0:Simulation",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1001,
          "title": "Constant",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1001"
        },
        {
          "id": 1002,
          "title": "Counter",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1002"
        },
        {
          "id": 1003,
          "title": "Random",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1003"
        },
        {
          "id": 1004,
          "title": "Sawtooth",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1004"
        },
        {
          "id": 1005,
          "title": "Sinusoid",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1005"
        },
        {
          "id": 1006,
          "title": "Square",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1006"
        },
        {
          "id": 1007,
          "title": "Triangle",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1007"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function recursive_func(data, target_id) {
    if (data["id"] == target_id) {
        return data;
    }
    if (!("children" in data)) {
        return undefined
    }
    let val = undefined
    for (let i = 0; i < data["children"].length; i++) {
        val = recursive_func(data["children"][i], target_id)
        if (val != undefined) {
            data["children"] = [val];
            return data;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}

function recursive_print_ids(data) {
    console.log(data['id'])
    if (!("children" in data)) {
        return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < data["children"].length; i++) {
        recursive_print_ids(data["children"][i])
    }
}

recursive_print_ids(recursive_func(data, '85/0:Simulation'))
console.log("") // whitespace in output
recursive_print_ids(recursive_func(data, 1006))
```

Edit: If you want to have multiple search IDs (e.g. 1005 and 1006) changing one argument to a list of IDs may work. Here is an example:

```js
const data = {
  "id": 85,
  "title": "Objects",
  "address": "i=85",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "85/0:Simulation",
      "title": "Simulation",
      "parent": "Objects",
      "address": "ns=3;s=85/0:Simulation",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 1001,
          "title": "Constant",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1001"
        },
        {
          "id": 1002,
          "title": "Counter",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1002"
        },
        {
          "id": 1003,
          "title": "Random",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1003"
        },
        {
          "id": 1004,
          "title": "Sawtooth",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1004"
        },
        {
          "id": 1005,
          "title": "Sinusoid",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1005"
        },
        {
          "id": 1006,
          "title": "Square",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1006"
        },
        {
          "id": 1007,
          "title": "Triangle",
          "parent": "Simulation",
          "address": "ns=3;i=1007"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function recursive_func(data, target_ids) {
    if (target_ids.includes(data["id"])) {
        return data;
    }
    if (!("children" in data)) {
        return undefined
    }
    let val = undefined
    let children = []
    for (let i = 0; i < data["children"].length; i++) {
        val = recursive_func(data["children"][i], target_ids)
        if (val != undefined) {
            children.push(val);
        }
    }
    if (children.length) {
        data["children"] = children;
        return data;
    }
    return undefined;
}

function recursive_print_ids(data) {
    if (!data) return;
    console.log(data['id'])
    if (!("children" in data)) {
        return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < data["children"].length; i++) {
        recursive_print_ids(data["children"][i])
    }
}

recursive_print_ids(recursive_func(data, ['85/0:Simulation']))
console.log("") // whitespace in output
recursive_print_ids(recursive_func(data, [1005, 1006]))
```

Comment: Yes, the principle of operation is correct, the recursive_function function is ideal, but can you conditionally pass several search arguments to it, for example 1006 and 1005, and it would output a structure with it?

Comment: I can make this modification if you explain what the output of passing both 1005 and 1006 would be.

Comment: @zaxarhic I took a guess at what you want the output to be. Let me know if you had something else in mind.

Comment: Buddy, this is what you need, I've been racking my head for about a week how to implement it, thank you very much

Comment: No problem, it was fun to think of the solution!